# Is cfmakeraw() available on Macos X / Unix C / C++?

Tags: c++, c, unix

I used a C / C++ code from the Internet, but my IDE gives me the following error on macos:

```
Use of undeclared identifier cfmakeraw
```

I now face the question, whether cfmakeraw is available on Macos / Unix ?

Thank you

Comment: Literally 5 seconds with a search engine results in this: https://linux.die.net/man/3/cfmakeraw - please make an effort yourself before asking.

Comment: From the Linux man page for cfmakeraw: "cfmakeraw() and cfsetspeed() are nonstandard, but available on the BSDs."

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Why are you looking up Linux man pages in response to a question about macOS?

Comment: @DietrichEpp The question also lists "Unix".

Comment: The Mac OS X man page for [cfmakeraw](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/cfmakeraw.3.html) says: "The cfmakeraw() and cfsetspeed() functions, as well as the TCSASOFT option to the tcsetattr() function are extensions to the IEEE Std 1003.1-1988 (``POSIX.1'') specification."

Comment: @StaceyGirl: Strictly speaking, Linux isn’t Unix. macOS **is** Unix.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I was just trying to show that if you do the absolute *minimum* research of typing the function name into a search engine, you learn something in just a few seconds. Add the OS name to the search query and you learn even more. This question could have been answered by OP in less than a minute by just searching online. That's the point I tried to make.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The OP clearly identified that they were using macOS. The cfmakeraw function is not standardized. The minimum level of effort here is to find a macOS man page. Linux man pages are not helpful, especially for nonstandard functions.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The Linux man page does provide some useful info regarding portability of `cfmakeraw` though - it says it's nonstandard, but available on the BSDs. Parts of FreeBSD and NetBSD were incorporated into Mac OS X via NextStep. I don't know if that pre-dates the inclusion of `cfmakeraw` into Mac OS X or not, since both are quite old.

Comment: @IanAbbott: That’s guesswork, requiring historical knowledge of macOS’s heritage. It’s also completely unnecessary. It makes me suspect that the only purpose of the “Literally 5 seconds” comment is to make fun of OP, rather than inform them of the correct answer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp There are many opinions for the criteria of being a "Unix". You are making it a little too easy for you with your absolute answer. It first of all depends, which aspect is important (compatibility, certification, trademark usage etc pp).

Comment: @DietrichEpp I agree it would have been more useful to start with the Mac OS man pages, then, if the function was found not to exist after all, refer to other systems' man pages (such as Linux) for backup.

Comment: @Ctx: The question **explicitly** states that the poster is using macOS, but you want to debate whether the *exact wording* of the question could be answered with a Linux man page, in spirit? You can’t have it both ways—answering the question “in spirit” because Unix might mean Linux, and answering it “to the letter”, ignoring the fact that the poster explicitly stated that they were on macOS.

Comment: @DietrichEpp What are you talking about? I just question your statement "Strictly speaking, Linux isn’t Unix. macOS is Unix" and added, that it depends a bit on the aspect of unix systems if it is correct or even helpful.

Comment: @Ctx: “Strictly speaking” is an English phrase that means that we are talking about exact definitions, and it provides a hint to the reader that colloquial terminology may be different. So, “Strictly speaking, Linux isn’t Unix” means, “According to technical usage of the terms, Linux isn’t Unix, even though you might say that Linux is Unix colloquially.”

Comment: @DietrichEpp It isn't even clear if "X is not unix" means, that it may not legally be called "unix" or that it isn't conforming to the SUS. So your "technical usage" itself is completely unclear. I am a bit puzzled that you didn't see that yourself before posting your last comment.

Comment: @Ctx: Linux does not conform to SUS. Also, Unix is a trademark. So Linux is not Unix for both reasons. This is neither relevant to the discussion nor useful to future visitors.

Comment: But your comment `StaceyGirl: Strictly speaking, Linux isn’t Unix. macOS is Unix.` was relevant to the discussion and/or useful to future visitors? I consider your comment harmful. Btw. there are Linux distributions that conform to SUS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your Mac, fire up Terminal and run `man cfmakeraw`.

```
SYNOPSIS
     #include <termios.h>

     void
     cfmakeraw(struct termios *termios_p);
```

So it is available, but you must include `<termios.h>`.